# I can't figure out how the average can be proven here to be greater than the variable shown

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a solution to a math problem and I can't figure out the algebra for the life of me.  How is
$$\frac{i+j}{2} > k$$ ?
My intution tells me that since the average of $\frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ is greater than 1, it works out but I can't figure out how to algebraically prove this.

---

[image]

Comment: Hint: $\;a + \dfrac{1}{a} \ge 2$ for all $a \gt 0$.

Comment: Think [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

Comment: I've become really rusty
for a + 1/a >= 2 for all a>0
Got any more hints lol
I can kinda see the AM-GM connection but I don't really know how to insert k into it

Comment: Had a realization on how to prove it so I'm good. the a + 1/a was the key for me. Thank you!!!!!